# Sheet.js how does encode_col and decode_col work?

Tags: sheetjs

How does `decode_col`, and `encode_col`, know which sheet to target if you never pass one in?

> `encode_col` / `decode_col` converts between 0-indexed columns and column names.

If I give it a column name, like "foobar" and that column exists in different sheets, or wholly different files I'm processing how will these two functions know where that column is?